# Cannot parse newDate() in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this code in a Mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate([
   {
      '$match':{
         'current.date':{
            $gt:new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate())).setHours(00,00,00))
         }
      }
   }
])
```

I read the query into a String and JSONReader return this error when I try to parse it:

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader expected an integer or a string but found 'new'.
```

Is there a way to parse `"new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate())).setHours(00,00,00))"` in Strict Mode?

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Comment: Aside from the fact that your query needs to be json and thus the value of `' $gt'` needs to be a string as per the exception I'd further assume that MongoDB can't use Java code directly. Additionally, what are you trying to do with all those new date objects (I count 4)?

Comment: Hello Thomas! Thank for reply me. Im trying to obtain dates whose dates are greater than my current date with hours at 0. For example, for today, I need to know the devices whose date are greater than (08/08/2019:00,00,00)

Comment: Do you wants to create new DATE in JAVA and pass in query or  wants to create new DATE in QUERY

Comment: In Java I do something like this:
Document myDocument = Document.parse(myRowQuery);
Where myRowQuery is a String with all my Mongo query

Comment: If `new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate())).setHours(00,00,00))` was supposed to be Java, it has two bugs in it: (1) `setDate()` returns void, and you can’t pass void to `new Date()`. (2) `setHours()` takes 1 argument, but you are trying to feed it three arguments.

Comment: Is not Java, is my Mongo query (mongo Shell Mode). In Java a try to create a document using a string with all my Mongo query something like this:
Document myDocument = Document.parse(myRowQuery); Where myRowQuery is a String with all my Mongo query

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

The query can be parsed as follows:

```
Document.parse("{ 'current.date':{ $gt: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) } }")
```